# Possible math contest question

Tags: discussion, contests

I've just discovered a possible math contest question...

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4069992/pqr-pqqrrp2021-find-all-triples-of-p-q-r-and-all-of-them-are-prime

The "$2021$" raised my suspicions, and from the wording of it (and lack of any effort in solving) I've flagged it for review.

EDIT: Thank you for all your responses.  Judging by the comments, this poster is persistent.  I wouldn't be surprised if they were posting under different names.

Comment: I’ve posted a comment as well. I would recommend posting a query as a comment in the future: this might signal potential responders to perhaps hold on in writing answers. Granted, the horse likely had bolted from this one by the time you raised the flag, but still.

Comment: Thanks - this was my first post here at meta, so I know now what to do.  At least if it isn't a contest question (i.e. it's legit) someone will point that out so it doesn't get pulled.

Comment: there are others today; one with exponents 2020 and 2022. I'm also not fond of the questions about contests that have finished.  One time I pressed really hard, told the OP (comments) that there was no friend who gave him the problem. Turned out there really was a friend, but the problem was from an entrance exam for a university...

Comment: @WillJagy I think you mean this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4070080/proving-that-if-a2020b2020-a2022b2022-then-ab-le-2-for-a-b

Comment: It is deleted now.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon - I saw it this morning...thanks!

Comment: New post from the same person, again with $2021$ in the problem (edit: just now deleted): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4070831/y2-2021x2-xy-equals-to-a-positive-integer-if-y-x-is-a-rational-number

Comment: @bjcolby15 For some reason, I did not get your response , but I happened to visit the question! +1 to your question, you and Theo above have also caught an impostor in the process, who I'm sure will be kept in check. Thanks!

Comment: Same question posted by another user [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4071580/72031). Looks like someone is dead serious to crack the contest by hook or by crook.

Comment: Why isn't that available anymore?

Comment: Click on search bar of the site and write 2021 inside it and press the "Enter" key. after the results appeared, click on "Newest" and you see there are lots of possible ongoing contest-math problems that are fully answered !

Comment: Yesterday I encountered this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4076557/2021-mathcounts-practice-competition-target-4-question-2?noredirect=1#comment8423465_4076557  OP insisted that he/she was truthful and I was thus lost as to whether I should have raised a flag on that question or not.

Comment: @EtackSxchange: That question linked by Paramanand has been deleted. Its title was "Triples Question in a Math Contest" and the author refuse to answer the question about whether the contest was ongoing or not.